# Using git-svn over svn + SASL with encryption

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, msysgit, sasl

Is it possible to launch git-svn over svn + SASL with encryption?

I've got an error can't establish connection.

```
C:\a\trunk>git svn clone svn://url/trunk 
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/a/trunk/trunk/.git/ 
Authorization failed: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 2167
```

**UPDATE** The issue presents only under Windows.

**UPDATE 2** The issue presents only with [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/). If you'll [install git via plain cygwin](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=818) everything will works fine

Comment: See my last update above

Comment: are you able to access the URL using SVN directly?

Comment: Yes, as you see in my example (i.e. encryption using SASL)

Comment: cygwin git works great!

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in the comments, msysgit does not include (to this day) support for secure svnserve communication with SASL so [using git (+ git-svn) on Cygwin](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=818) seems the only available choice.

But what the previous tutorial doesn't reference, are the necessary libraries to make SASL work with plain git on cygwin.
So you will need to also install this packages (all available from the cygwin setup):

- perl-Authen-SASL
- perl-Term-ReadKey
- libsasl2_3 (*)

(*) Not quite sure this one is required but also installed this one and everything went smooth.

In order to clone a secured svn repo with SASL.

Comment: I am sure underneath the covers, these details were taken care of, but it was enough for me to install git and gitsvn in cygwin on Windows 10, then I was off to the races.